# Relationship between ReadLine and disk access

Tags: c#, io, c#-2.0, readline, streamreader

I am currently using a code construction like this:

```
 string line;
 using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("somelargefile.txt"))
 {
     while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
     // do something
 }
```

I use this to read in a very large text file. (I need to evaluate line by line, and some lines need to be stored in memory). I find it strange that this piece of code does not cause performance penalties. I assumed that every `ReadLine` call would result in an access to the disk making my program extremely slow on files that are several hundreds of megabytes large. But it appears to be quite fast actually.  Why is this?

Is there no relationship between ReadLine and physical disk access then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StreamReader`, and I believe its parent class `TextReader`, use a buffered read.  The system reads a block of raw data first.  You can use the `DiscardBuffer()` method of `StreamReader` to empty this buffer manually, but I am not aware of a way to access it.

MSDN has a detailed [explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff565356.aspx) of the principles.

Answer (score 2):

The information required is read line by line by your process but the operating system will access the file by mapping the file to memory. So when you read in a line in the same memory page the access is quite fast. There will be a disk access when the page is not available in the memory and there is a page fault. That time operating system will check out some unwanted page and load the required page into memory. Read through Paging and memory access in operating systems.

Comment: This is definitely the case for memory mapped files, but does .NET really use them behind the scenes for normal Streams..? I would expect any buffering to be done in user land.

Comment: .Net does not do this specifically. As @jonsca said there is some buffering done within .Net. But the memory mapping is done in the background by the OS. Read through this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641614/memory-mapping-of-files-vs-createfile-readfile . The same thing applies to .Net too.